# What comes first - InjectableProvider(s) or ExceptionMapper(s)?

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I haven't found an answer to the question above. How can I **throw an exception from InjectableProvider**, and get **caught in ExceptionMapper**, in order to provide a custom response?

Comment: Have you actually tried to write some code? It could work as expected..

Answer (score 1):

**Alex**, **Pavel**,

I have tried this myself with:

- a Joda `DateTime` injectable provider: `PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider<PathParam, DateTime>`
- a mapper that converts exceptions into objects serializable in a format accepted by the client (XML, JSON, etc.): `ExceptionMapper<WebApplicationException>`

Based on my experiment, it seems that any `WebApplicationException` thrown in the `InjectableProvider` **bypasses the exception mapper**, and is therefore not  properly formatted.

I have also tried:

- adding an `ExceptionMapper<ParamException>`,
- renaming the classes hoping the order in which these are wired follows alphabetical order,

but no luck so far.

@**Pavel** / anyone from Jersey: any advice would be welcome!

Thanks,

Marc.

---

**UPDATE**

If you wrap the logic in your `InjectableProvider` in a `try`/`catch` block, then in the `catch` block, the trick is to:

1. create your serializable POJO / your custom response,
2. wrap it into a `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` with the appropriate status code and/or media type,
3. pass it to the `WebApplicationException`, as the entity parameter.

@**Pavel** / anyone from Jersey: any alternative which would avoid this additional logic and make things "just work"?